# PHP - How to keep program still run when have error

Tags: try-catch

In the example code:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <=20; $i++) {
        echo $i . '<br />';
        if ($i == 10) {
            $haha->hoho("hehe");
        }
    }
?>
```

When $i = 10 program will show this error, `Call to a member function hoho() on a non-object` because $haha is not a object and the program stops running. I want the program to handle this error and continue running to $i=20. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

#### The Simple answer: Fix your code.

Long answer:

There is lots of ways to do that, the first thing off the top of my head is to use [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) regardless of your programming pattern.

But if you are doing it in OOP you should make use of [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)([what?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)) like [`__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) -obviously the `$haha` needs to be the object in your example.

> Hint: Using [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in magic methods is really good idea. but
> you can't handle this directly with exception because Internal PHP
> functions mainly use Error reporting, only modern Object oriented
> extensions use exceptions.

Comment: you can write example for me about code above ? document about Exception unintelligible for me :(

Comment: Check the example on the Exception on the official PHP Documentation that I have linked, I wouldn't be able to write simpler then that anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <=20; $i++) {
        echo $i . '<br />';
        if ($i == 10) {
            if ($haha) $haha->hoho("hehe");
        }
    }
?>
```

This should check if `$haha` exists before it tries to do `$haha->hoho("hehe");`

Comment: this is first solution for me, but in my function use a lot of `$haha` so i can not use `if($haha)` because look at complicated

Comment: "Looks complicated" is not a good reason not to do something pretty standard and simple.